# Filling gap between tiles fixed on gypsum board and gypsum board

Tags: drywall

Tiles fixed on gypsum board by silicon and there is a gap inbetween at door space , because of bad gypsum board installation . How to fill this gap? Thankx

Comment: How about a few pictures.

Comment: A picture will help, but usually a bad installation means a redo for best repair.  Possible some door trim will fix/hide it.